# DTO as array in ServiceStack

Tags: swagger, servicestack

I'm attempting to migrate a Web API service to ServiceStack with minimum (no) change to the service definition, but am having trouble creating an operation with an array as the body parameter, like in the Web API service:

[image]

But if I use a DTO-array, like in the following, the operation disappears from Swagger:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A request class that inherits from a list of T should do what you want.

Eg

```
public class PatchCustomer : List<ApiCustomer>
{
}
```